# Local variables disappear in CLion 2021.2

Tags: c++, debugging, clion, watch, local-variables

I'm trying to debug a non-optimized build of a C++ test executable in a repository of mine, with CLion 2021.2. I start debugging, and at some point tell the CLion debugger to run up to some breakpoint - and when I reach it, the local variables are no longer listed. The variables/watches pane is empty, saying only:

> "Variables are not available"

... and they are unavailable even if I walk up the stack to the calling function, where, when I broke earlier, did show the variables.

What are the possible reasons (I assume there aren't many) for this occurring? Can this be "legit" or is it an IDE bug?

Notes:

- The breakpoint is in an innocent-looking C(ish) function, not in any templated code, lambda or anything like that.
- If I *manually* add watches - they work, i.e. I see the appropriate values getting updated.

Comment: Maybe you are running an optimized version of your program?

Comment: Are you by chance setting a breakpoint in a non capturing lambda?

Comment: @WBuck: No, I'm not.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: No, I'm not that clueless :-P Also, note that the variables in other functions up the stack are also gone.

Comment: @einpoklum could you please submit a ticket in CLion [tracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/CPP)?

Comment: @MaximBanaev: If I could reproduce it right now, maybe I would.